# How can I make my bootstrap and jquery work inside Wamp virtual host?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4, wamp, virtualhost

I had setup a virtual host in my WAMP server called myweb.local, when I created an index.php and added some bootstrap class and jquery, it does not work when I enter myweb.local in my browser (Google Chrome and Firefox). Here's the image:
[using Virtual Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K28kh.jpg)

But when I tried to use localhost/mysite/index.php, its working properly. Here's the image: [using Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJmfi.jpg)

I wonder how I will make Bootstrap and Jquery works inside virtual host?

This is my Virtual Host Setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myweb.local
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/mysite"
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/mysite/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

Setup in hosts inside C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1   myweb.local
::1 myweb.local
```

Setup in httpd.conf inside C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf

```
 Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

As you run under Windows environment, in `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` you should use `\` instead of `/` on paths.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but when I tried that it doesn't work on me and received additional 2 of 3 services running error in Wamp

Comment: Try to use ```/``` in ```DocumentRoot``` and ```\``` in ```Directory``` node

Comment: If your path doesn't have spaces, you don't need to include double quotes in ```DocumentRoot```